# How to get interval of repeat events in R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

In below mentioned dataframe, I want to calculate Median, Mode and Average time of repeat events.

Median, Mode and Average should be in seconds/minute as well as days also.

Difference of repeat interval should be considering `minimum_date` against each num and at what time interval next row added.

Test_DF

```
Num                   Date                    
1asc & 251.54         2018-04-01 20:16:32     
1asc & 251.54         2018-04-01 20:46:32
1asc & 251.54         2018-04-02 20:16:32
2fet = 247.94         2018-04-03 15:16:32
2fet = 247.94         2018-04-03 15:20:32
2fet = 247.94         2018-04-03 15:24:32
```

Required Output:

```
Num     minimum_date        max_date                        Median    Mode    Avg
1asc & 251.54       2018-04-01 20:16:32 2018-04-02 20:16:32 720 min   720 min 720 min
2fet = 247.94       2018-04-03 15:16:32 2018-04-03 15:24:32 4 sec     4 sec   4 sec
```

Comment: Dput(testdf) would bei helpful

Comment: @Christoph This is the sample dataframe.

Comment: @user9211845 what we mean is that if you give us `dput(Test_DF)` then we can all use exactly the same dataframe as you are using.

Comment: Said a different way: these columns could be `character`, `factor`, or (in one case) `POSIXt`, which changes things. Additionally, when there are spaces in the values, it is less-trivial to jusy copy and absorb into a local R instance. You can make it significantly easier on us and more obvious what the data is by allowing us to copy the output from your `dput(Test_DF)` (or `dput(head(...))` if large) in addition to or instead of this columnar output (which might look better on the eyes).

Comment: Additionally, this is not a free code service. Though often somebody may just do it for you anyway, it is strongly preferred to do your own research and try something, even if we eventually tell you that you're going down the wrong path, showing you've put in some effort will go a long way towards us wanting to help you.